# How can I transform a remote none-bare repos to a bare reopos without re-clone in local machine in git?

Tags: git

I have a remote machine RemoteMachine which hold the clone of another MachineWeNotConcern with:

```
git clone MachineWeNotConcern/prj prj
```

My local machine clone like this:

```
git clone RemoteMachine/prj local_prj
```

Now I want to make the RemoteMachine's repos to bare(how?) as if I checked with:

```
git clone --bare MachineWeNotConcern/prj prj
```

And I don't want to re-clone from my bare repos of the RemoteMachine because it always takes to much time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a new clone from your *local repo on the remote machine* of the project with --bare. ie:

```
git clone --bare prj bare_prj
```

Then delete the original prj. This would be faster than cloning it from the original machine again.

EDIT: Another solution:

It looks like you could make your repo into a bare repo by:

- changing the .git/config file to have bare = true instead of bare = false
- removing the contents of prj/* other than the .git file
- moving the .git dir contents into prj/ and removing the .git dir

At least, this seems to work for me, but there could be reasons this would fail, for all I know.