# Is there a git uncheckout?

Tags: git, git-checkout

With `git clone` there is the option `-n` wich prevents a checkout of `HEAD` after the repository is cloned. Is there a possibility to do this manually?

**Edit** I think the option `-n` reads better in the manual than it actually is: After cloning with `-n` all my tools show that I still reside on the master branch; the only difference being that all files are shown as deleted. It’s not really the same situation that I would call ‘not checked out’.

So maybe I should just delete `HEAD`?

Comment: If you're trying to make a bare repo from a non-bare one, I think this was already covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/git-convert-normal-to-bare-repository

Comment: No, I just want to *uncheckout*; e.g. have the same repo a `git clone -n` would give me.

Comment: just completed my answer to emulate a `git clone -n`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to clone it bare:

```
git clone --bare your_repo bare_repo
```

(and delete your checked out repo)

Basically, you need to transform your repo into a bare one, which, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743648/how-can-i-transform-a-remote-none-bare-repos-to-a-bare-reopos-without-re-clone-in), could be done manually with:

> - changing the `.git/config` file to have `bare = true` instead of `bare = false`
> - removing the contents of `your_repo/*` other than the `.git` file
> - moving the `.git` dir contents into `your_repo/` and removing the `.git` dir

See also [Git: Convert normal to bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/git-convert-normal-to-bare-repository), as mentioned by [MikeSep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149170/mikesep) in the comments.

If you need to uncheckout, keep `bare` to `false`, and simply remove everything but the `.git`. That should be like a `git clone -n`.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I really tried `clone -n`, I saw that indeed it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I read the original question as wanting to preserve the repo, but delete the working tree. This is useful when you want to put a project on the backburner, after some work has been done with it.

One solution is to create a branch with an empty working tree, and check out the empty branch:

```
git checkout --orphan archived
git reset --hard
git commit -m "Project is archived" --allow-empty
```

Explanation:

1. `git checkout --orphan archived` creates the branch `archived`, with unrelated history to the project.
2. `git reset --hard` removes versioned files that exist in the working tree. It preserves unversioned files, which can be cleaned out with `git clean -fd` if necessary.
3. `git commit -m "Project is archived" --allow-empty` creates a commit with no files on the `archived` branch.

Unlike the `git clone -n` option, this method:

- does not leave the index showing all files as "deleted"
- unambiguously documents what happened to the work tree. The current branch name will be "`archived`"

A repo thusly 'archived' is ready to be re-activated by `git checkout master`, and can subsequently be re-archived with `git checkout archived`